# Does virtual machine extensions provisioned for existing VM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

We have a VM ARM template which runs a custom extension when we provision it. This extensions run fine and install framework correctly.

By looking at verbose log it seems like it runs the extension every time we run deployment script even if VM is already present. Is this correct?

Also if it does run the extension every time, is there anyway to avoid it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basically every time the VM is rebooted or the same template is deployed again, the extension is run but only if the new configuration is different from the old one. It can rerun if the force rerun flag is set.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Where is the "force rerun" flag documented?

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP was asking how to prevent the extension from running after every deployment.
Your response answers the question, "How do I re-run the CustomScriptExtension?"

I've searched for this "force rerun" and couldn't find anything. Microsoft's suggestion is to remove the extension from the VM or VMSS and then re-deploy the ARM template.